# When called setPosition, how does a sprite move slowly

Tags: java, libgdx

I am new to LibGDX library,
I am building the Snakes and ladders game with it.
I have a player class, it extends itself from Sprite class.
I want it to move when a dice is thrown.
But it becomes suddenly, I cannot see the movement.

```
public void updatePlayer(){
    //this.setPosition(body.getPosition().x, body.getPosition().y);
    game.getBatch().begin();
    draw(game.getBatch());
    game.getBatch().end();
}

public void updatePlayer(int dice){
    if (dice > 0 && dice <= 6){
        for (int i = 0; i < dice; i++){
            float laterX = getX() + 48;
            if (laterX > GameInfo.WIDTH - 20){
                //setPosition(3, getY() + 5f);
                translateY(5);
                updatePlayer();
               
            }else {
                
                translateX(5);
                //setPosition(getX() + 5, getY());
                updatePlayer();
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot see movement 'cause you set the position. Use translate to move it.
[doc](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Sprite.html#translate-float-float-)

```
Sprite#setPosition() //Sets the position where the sprite will be drawn
Sprite#translate()  //Sets the position relative to the current position where the sprite will be drawn.
```

My loop class:

```
public class Game extends ScreenAdapter {

private static String worldName;
private EntityPlayer player;
private FlatWorld flatWorld;
public static World world;
//    private Box2DDebugRenderer debugRenderer;
private static boolean pauseGame;

public Game(String worldName){
    world = new World(new Vector2(0, 0), false);
    //this.debugRenderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer();
    this.worldName = worldName;
    this.player = PlayerDiskUtils.readPlayerFromDisk(this.worldName);
    this.flatWorld = FlatWorldUtils.loadFlatWorld(this.worldName);
    this.player.setCamera(this.flatWorld.getWorldSize());
    this.flatWorld.setBlocksCourt(FlatWorldUtils.readBlocksCourt(this.flatWorld.getWorldSize().getWidth(), this.flatWorld.getWorldSize().getHeight(), this.worldName));
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new GameInputAdapter());
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    world.step(1/60f, 6, 2);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 1f);

    this.flatWorld.getBlocksCourt().renderWorld(player.getCamera());
    this.player.update(this.flatWorld, this.flatWorld.getWorldSize().getWidth(), this.flatWorld.getWorldSize().getHeight());
    this.flatWorld.blocks.renderBlocks(this.player.getCamera());
    this.player.renderInventory();
    this.player.playerHud.render(this.player.states.getHealth(), this.player.states.getHungry(), this.player.states.getThirsty());
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    this.pause();
    world = null;
    worldName = null;
    this.flatWorld.blocks.disposeBlocks();
}

@Override
public void pause() {
    super.pause();
    PlayerDiskUtils.writePlayerToDisk(this.worldName, this.player);
    FlatWorldUtils.saveFlatWorld(this.worldName, this.flatWorld);
}

public static String getWorldName() { return worldName; }
public static boolean isPauseGame() { return pauseGame; }
public static void setPauseGame(boolean pauseGame) { Game.pauseGame = pauseGame; }


/**
 * This is the input adapter of the player.
 * Here keys and input event are set
 */
private class GameInputAdapter extends InputAdapter{

    @Override   //Mouse moving
    public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) { return player.rotatePlayerToMouse(); }

    @Override   //Keys
    public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
        if(keycode == Input.Keys.ESCAPE){ if(player.inventoryOpen) player.inventoryOpen = false;}
        if(keycode == Input.Keys.E){ player.inventoryOpen = !player.inventoryOpen; }
        return true;
    }

    @Override   //Mouse buttons
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        Vector3 mouseCords3 = player.getCamera().unproject(new Vector3(screenX, screenY, 0));
        return onBodyClick(new Vector2(mouseCords3.x, mouseCords3.y), button);
    }

    private boolean onBodyClick(Vector2 mouseCords, int button){
        if(player.inventoryOpen) return false;
        final Body[] body = new Body[1];

        //Save inside body[0] the body which has been clicked
        world.QueryAABB(fixture -> {
            if(fixture.testPoint(mouseCords)){
                body[0] = fixture.getBody();
            }
            return true;
        }, mouseCords.x, mouseCords.y, mouseCords.x + 0.5f, mouseCords.y + 0.5f);


        if(body[0] == null){
            if(button == Input.Buttons.RIGHT){
                player.onPlayerRightClick(flatWorld, mouseCords);
            }
        }else{
            if(button == Input.Buttons.RIGHT){
                ((Block)body[0].getUserData()).onBlockClicked(player);
            }else if(button == Input.Buttons.LEFT){
                player.onPlayerBlockDestroying(flatWorld, (Block)body[0].getUserData(), mouseCords);
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

}

My code about player moving(it is 3d model, but it coult help you):

```
     public void move(FlatWorld flatWorld, int worldWidth, int worldHeight) {

    int x = 0, y = 0;
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.W))
        y = 1;
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.S))
        y = -1;
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.A))
        x = -1;
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.D))
        x = 1;

    if(x != 0 || y != 0) {
        if (this.canPlayerMove(flatWorld, new Vector3(x, y, 0), worldWidth, worldHeight)) {
            this.modelInstance.transform.translate(x, y, 0);
            this.moveCamera(worldWidth, worldHeight);
        }
    }
    this.renderModel(null);
}
```

As you can see, I translate my model without call setPosition()

Comment: How can use the translate() function. I read the documentation which you sent, and I search it on WEB, but I couldn't manage. Can you share a bunch of code pls?

Comment: You said your player class extends Sprite one... you should be able to invoke translate with don notation...

Comment: Yes, I have done this, but it didn't change anything, I am still seeing the movement suddenly.

Comment: Ok, You can see now, I added moveRight() method.

Comment: Maybe you should delete ```body.getPosition().set(getX(), getY());``` after moveRight() calling. I don't know what that method does, but if it sets position of your sprite, of course you cannot see movement: it translate and then set position. If it does what I've just said, try deleting it

Comment: Actually, my problem is simply the movement of sprite between two points and I need to see the passes among squares.

Comment: I don't know much/anything about LWJGL, but does it actually initiate render calls after you call these method? Because if it doesn't, then your for loop is essentially the same as calling .translate(48) once.

Comment: @Beko is right. Translate must be called once. It doesn't need to call a lots of time in a loop. I am gonna post a my code. It's about a model (3D player) but it moves on a 2D map. It could help you...

Comment: @DynoZ, I am confused. What is the difference between setPosition() and translate(). If I wanted it to move in the render method, I would already do this with setPosition(). What's the meaning of the translate() method.

Comment: ```Sprite#setPosition()``` set the position of your sprite directly without make it move smoothly. ```Sprite#translate()``` translate (move smoothly) it. Notice that translate need relative argument: if your sprite is at 0;5 and you wanna move it to 5,5, you don't need to call Sprite#translate(5, 5), but call it with (5, 0), this 'cause it is relative...

Comment: p.s. A tip: this is libGDX basic, you should learn them before. Docs are programmers' best friend [doc](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Spritebatch%2C-Textureregions%2C-and-Sprites). Also I am gonna link my gitHub project in order to help you to get better how/when use translate/setPosition.

Comment: I think that's related to frame per second. Because, for my problem, I have a dice, and I want to see all movements along the way. When a dice is thrown, since it is 60 fps it's happened very quickly. Then we don't catch it. Do you think can I solve this, with body and linearVelocity ?

Comment: Get it! Have you tried calling only translate? without setPosition()? And where actually you get stuck on?

Comment: I edited my code again, I tried without setPosition(). But Nothing changed. It is giving the same effect with setPosition().

Comment: How much are you translating your sprite?

Comment: 5f for every dice step

Comment: Try moving your sprite of 1f on render() when you press a key.

Comment: I can do this, it's working on render() method. But I want to do this in my sprite class.

Comment: But sprite moving method must be called on render(). Dude, maybe I didn't understand your achieve...?! You wanna move smoothly your sprite, instead you got stuck on cause you cannot see moving (but it sets position). Is that your goal?